# Typescript Promise file upload

Tags: typescript

Hi every one im trying to open a dialog window after every file is uploaded to a server. However the window is opening first before all the files are uploaded. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
public UploadAll() {

    this.doAsyncTask().then(() => 

    this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
        height: '200px',
        width: '300px',
    }));
}

doAsyncTask() {

    var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.fileUploads.forEach((fileUpload) => {
        fileUpload.upload();
        resolve();
    });
});
return promise;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to open a dialog after each file is uploaded or after all files are uploaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with your code is that you resolve the promise on first `fileUpload` and also you don't wait until upload finishes

```
public UploadAll() {

    this.doAsyncTask().then(() => 

    this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
        height: '200px',
        width: '300px',
    }));
}

doAsyncTask() {

 return Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const promises : Array<Promise> = [];
    this.fileUploads.forEach((fileUpload) => {
           promises.push(fileUpload.upload());
    });
    Promise.all(promises)
         .then(() => resolve())
         .catch((err) => reject(err));
  });
}
```

Comment: @JeremiahMora you are welcome, if it's working, please kindly mark it as `answer` so other users with same problem will know that it's a solution